# Disable all controls on a page except controls in a particular div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all controls in a page using jquery except controls contained in a particular div.

```
 $('input,select,textarea,div:not("#viewNotice")').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I have tried using above selector, but its not working good. Here I am disabling all `input, select and textarea` controls leaving **viewNotive div**.

Note: In viewNotice div I have a JqGrid. I dont want to disable jqgrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using something like a modal layer instead. This would be much simpler in many ways. However, you can try the following:

```
$(':input').not('#viewNotice :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

The selector you used selected all divs that did not have an id of `viewNotice` (amongst other elements). This piece of code selects all input elements (see [jQuery's selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for `:input`) and excludes all inputs that are contained in `#viewNotice` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z2wYn/

take a look at this fiddle.